# Dropdown menu hover with position fixed not working

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown

I am struggling with the following: I have a navigation bar on which I want to show a dropdown when hovering over a particular item.

When I hover over the particular item, the dropdown appears as expected but it does not persist if I move the mouse away from the items which triggers showing the dropdown.

Could anyone advise on how to resolve this?

The logic is:

```
<span class="navigation_bar_product_category">
<div class="backdrop"/> </span>
```

This is the CSS code I used:

```
.navigation_bar_product_category {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    z-index:1;
  };
  .backdrop {
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    display:none;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:2;
    right: 0px;
    left:0px;
    position:fixed;
    top:70px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
};
.navigation_bar_product_category:hover .backdrop {
    display:block;
  }
```

Any support is much appreciated!

Comment: Try to post a snippet of code that can be reproduced and tested. This code is incomplete and therefore more difficult to test and see what's wrong

Comment: Post the complete code